# Regular expression to remove trailing chars

Tags: php, regex

I'm looking for a regular expression in Php that could transform incoming strings like this:

```
abaisser_negation_pronominal_question     => abaisser_n_p_q
abaisser_pronominal_question              => abaisser_p_q
abaisser_negation_question                => abaisser_n_q
abaisser_negation_pronominal              => abaisser_n_p
abaisser_negation_voix_passive_pronominal => abaisser_n_v_p_p
abaisser                                  => abaisser
```

With the Php code close to something like:

```
$line=preg_replace("/<h3>/im", "", $line);
```

How would you do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `\K` or positive lookbehind.

```
$input = preg_replace('~_.\K[^_\n]*~', '', $input);
```

Pattern `_.` in the above regex would match an `_` and also the character following the underscore. `\K` discards the previously matched characters that is, `_` plus the following character. It won't take these two characters into consideration. Now `[^_\n]*` matches any character but not of an `_` or a `\n` newline character zero or more times. So the characters after the character which was preceded by an underscore would be matched upto the next `_`  or `\n` character. Removing those characters will give you the desired output.

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/cV1nF5/5)

```
$input = preg_replace('~(?<=_.)[^_\n]*~', '', $input);
```

It just looks after to the `_` and the character following the `_` and matches all the characters upto the next underscore or newline  character.

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/cV1nF5/6)

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
$input = preg_replace('/(_[A-Za-z])[^_\n]*/', '$1', $input);
```

#### [RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/cV1nF5/3)

**Explanation:**

- This regex searches for `(_[A-Za-z])[^_\n]*` which means underscore followed by single letter and then match before a newline or underscore
- It capture first part `(_[A-Za-z])` in a backreference `$1`
- Replacement is `$1` leaving underscore and first letter in the replacement string

Answer (score 0):

```
$line = preg_replace("/_([a-z])([a-z]*)/i", "_$1", $line);
```

Comment: Hi, here's the error: `PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function preg_replace_all() in [...]`

Comment: Oh yes, that should just be preg_replace

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex

```
$input = preg_replace('/_(.)[^\n_]+/', '_$1', $input);
```

[**DEMO**](https://regex101.com/r/cV1nF5/4)

What it does is capture the character after `_` and match till `\n` or `_` is encountered and replaced with the `_$1` which means `_` plus the character captured.